# File Deleted Using the Notepad++ "Delete From Disk" Option

Tags: notepad++, delete-file

A file was deleted from my Windows XP (SP2) using the "Delete From Disk" option at Notepad++ (v5.0.3) accidentally. It didn't ask for confirmation and the file is not in the Recycle Bin.
I've tried to undelete using a dedicated app; Nothing; It had been evaporated.

Is there a way to retrieve the file?
What on earth were the guys at Notepad++  thinking...?

Comment: Don't touch anything, install data recovery software on external drive and try to recover the lost file.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I wouldn't ever use this piece of crap software if I wasn't forced to do at my current workplace.

Answer (score 0):

Recuva
MiniTool Power Data Recovery
EASEUS Data Recovery Wizard

All work rather well in file recovery as long as you do not not "write over" the place on the hard drive where the file is stored.

If it is an important file I would disconnect the drive, install a recovery program on another computer/drive and access the drive from there.